# Docker seems to use a cache when I run my phpunit test

Tags: php, docker

I have a phpunit unit test:

```php
public function testSum(): void
{
    var_dump('Hello world!!');
    exit;

    self::assertTrue(true);
}
```

First, I run this:

```
$ docker-compose stop && docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans --no-recreate
$ docker-compose exec php php -n vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml --filter testSum
```

The output is `Hello world!!` as expected.

However, when I edit my test by removing the echo and the exit commands,

```php
public function testSum(): void
{
    self::assertTrue(true);
}
```

and I run

`docker-compose exec php php -n vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml --filter testSum`

I still get `Hello world!!`. Even when I run it tens of times, the result is the same.

But if I stop and start my docker container the test runs correctly.

It seems to be a docker cache that I'm not able to purge.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use cache then

`docker build --no-cache -t [imageName]`

or for compose

`docker-compose build --no-cache`